# How to make an event repeat on the Wednesday following the 3rd Monday of every month in Google Calendar or iCal file format?

Tags: google-calendar, icalendar

Is this possible to do in Google Calendar or .iCal format?

I've explored `rrule.js` options at [this site](http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/#/rfc/FREQ=MONTHLY;WKST=MO;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) to write script that will create events series in your Google Calendar.

Using [`CreateEventSeries()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createeventseriestitle,-starttime,-endtime,-recurrence) you can create event with `Wednesday following the 3rd Monday of every month` recurrence rule:

```
function createEventSeries() {
      var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventSeries('Team Meeting',
        new Date(),
        new Date(),
        CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
          .addWeeklyRule()
          .onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY)
          .onlyOnMonthDays([17,18,19,20,21,22,23])
    );
    Logger.log('Event Series ID: ' + eventSeries.getId());
}
```